What is the tick next to the "0 answers"?
I just noticed that there was a tick next to the "0 answers" of a question on the home page (and when searching for it). I never saw that before, what does it mean?


There is an accepted but deleted answer.

question unanswered successfully

"This [ answer ] is hidden. It was flagged as plagiarism and deleted 9 hours ago."

@Basic it has since been manually undeleted and re-deleted (for other reasons, I think?) by a moderator.  Here's another example that still shows the issue.

It means that the asker has accepted the fact that their question will remain unanswered /j

The question has a deleted accepted answer.
It seems that the system still considers it when determining if a question has an accepted answer. This seems like a bug.
A lot of questions in the same state can be found when searching for hasaccepted:yes answers:0 locked:no1. However, a site search cannot find all instances of it, since a question with two answers, one deleted and one not, will not be easily identifiable via searching.
1 the locked:no filters out merged questions

Interestingly, it seems almost all such answers are by the same individual. I suspect that the "bug" was caused by the bulk action that was taken by the community user against content made by that specific user.

@ThomA not all. Probably a lot and the most recent ones but this is a counter example. It's the oldest result in that search. It seems it's a system problem, rather than a problem with specific moderator action.

@VLAZ Fascinatingly, that answer is deleted, but not (according to the UI) by any specific user; there's no history event recording it having been done.

Why I said, almost all, @VLAZ . The penultimate answer in that search is also by that user.

One thing to add is that normally, when an accepted answer is deleted, the accept vote on the answer is removed (see also). However, in some rare cases, it's not removed. Per @RyanM above, the answer was deleted without a revision history item, which likely explains why it wasn't removed here. Most likely, the system doesn't account for this edge case here and in other places.

To clarify, the one linked in the question has a revision history item for the deletion. The one VLAZ linked in a comment does not.

@RyanM Has this ever happened before? Any possible reasons for there to be no record whatsoever?

@SyedM.Sannan There are a few other examples in the search linked in this answer.  My guess would be that the functionality that adds the revision history entry was added later on in the Stack Exchange platform, and that these deletions simply predate it being added. I've seen other examples of places where the history entries (of various sorts, some mod-only) for very old actions appear differently than they would if those actions were performed today.

The deletion happened 13 years ago, so it's very likely to be lack of or worse deletion logging in certain circumstances. Especially around deletion, logging used to be far worse to non-existent in certain cases. I've never heard of this happening around answers, but this type of behaviour has happened Elsewhere:tm:. It's also possible that it behaved weirdly with account deletion instead, which remains one of the more worse covered areas, both historically and ongoing

I've re-deleted all of the answers in the bulk action on 2024-04-25 which were left as accepted while deleted. So, all of those are no longer accepted. That leaves 13 found in the search provided in this answer.

Moderators can search for these with isaccepted:yes deleted:yes. There are, currently, 8,101 such answers. Nearly all of them are from 2012 or earlier (24 from 2013, and 34 from >= 2014).
